# Timestamp changes while sends from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, time

There is really strange situation about I have to idea how to fix.

I have JS-code:

```
 // insert record in table
        var jsonForServer = {
            'date'    : $scope.selectedCalendarEvent,
            'typeDate': 'local',
            'events'  : $scope.userClickedEvents.fullListTitles
        };
        // save to server
                $http.post('calendar/updatedate', { calendar_record: jsonForServer })
                    .success(function(response)
                    {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
```

Here, checking in debugger, I found that $scope.selectedCalendarEvent has value `Mon Feb 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200`

But when I get this json on server, I'm getting the next:

```
2014-02-09T22:00:00.000Z
```

which indicates day before I get in JS (and at 22.00).

My PHP code is here:

```
$calendar = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$dateToInsert =  $calendar->calendar_record->date;
```

jsonForServer:

```
Object {date: Tue Feb 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Финляндия (зима)), typeDate: "local", events: Array[1]}
date: Tue Feb 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Финляндия (зима))
events: Array[1]
typeDate: "local"
```

It looks very strange for me.

Comment: could be the local and server time are different.

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code?

Comment: Remember JS uses milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: I have local server which uses system's time, which is equals JS-time.

Comment: can you post the output of `jsonServer`?